# Core Data and Userdefaults not storing data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, default

Core Data and UserDefaults not storing data when my application is closed.

I am getting notification when my application is closed so i store it in core data and defaults to do some stuff.

when the application is open it is storing all informations but only application is closed its not working, any idea to do it.

I stored my data in the following function.

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            let response = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
             //here i will send response will store to core date
            self.defaults.set("1", forKey: "notifyid")
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually u misunderstand the question bro. i receive the push notification when my application is closed. i have a functionality to store notification data. Now its not storing when my application is closed. its working fine when application in open.

Comment: Your `willPresent` function is not called if the app is closed.

Comment: i cannot debug the application when its closed. can u give any suggestion

Comment: i think willPresent function is not calling.

Comment: That is what I already told you.

Comment: any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You are storing it in wrong function. Will Present only gets called when the app is in Foreground. so it will not work when app is in background, Instead of Will Present function use did receive remote function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    let response = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    self.defaults.set("1", forKey: "notifyid")    
}
```

> Note: Please make sure in your app capabilities under Background Modes your remote notification and background fetch. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Bro i have used Notification service and Notification Content for rich custom push notification, this function will not hit, any other suggestions.